# How to create a loop calculating the summation of exponents

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create a loop that will evaluate this equation.

```
     10
y =  ∑X^j
    j=0
```

When x = 5. I am trying to use this code

```
y=0 # initialize y to 0
x = 5
for(i in 1:5){y[i] = (exp(x[0:10]))}

print(y)
```

but I can't seem to even get the exponents right, let alone the summation. Anyone know how to use a for loop to evaluate this sum?

Comment: `x = 5; sum(x**(0:10))`

Comment: I need to use a for loop to create this, not sum

Comment: Homework? Cannot abide assignments that force you to code in slow error-prone ways.

Comment: hey.. weird that you need a loop, but you need to do y = y+ x^(i) .. and note, exp is the exponential function, not power which you have in the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is mixing a `for` loop with a `sequence` which is likely not going to produce the results you want.  Also, the error that "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" shows there is a problem with the sequence and trying to index a single value.

```
x <- 5
y <- 0

for (i in 0:10) {
  y <- y + x ^ i
}
```

Comparing the results to the most succint way listed above shows the results are the same.

```
> setequal(y, sum(x^(0:10)))
[1] TRUE
```